# When a data object references another data object, how to use in 11ty (or nunjucks)?

Tags: json, nunjucks, eleventy

I have data objects that reference other data objects.

For example:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "object A id",
    "key1": "value1",
    "linked": [
       {
         "_id": "_object B id"
       }
...
```

In javascript, I would do something like an ES6 `find()`, but is there a 11ty-ish way to do this smartly/dynamically? Specifically in templating, if I want `key1` from object B, how do I make that reference in nunjucks? Do I need to specify two data sources in my template? What does the nunjucks template tag look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [custom eleventy collection](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/collections/#advanced-custom-filtering-and-sorting) in your `.eleventy.js` file, that takes in the linked ID and uses the `find()` to attach the `B` object, which you can then access in nunjucks template:

Something like:

```
eleventyConfig.addCollection("linkedObjects", function(collectionApi) {
    // get items
    const objectAs = collectionApi.getFilteredByGlob("objectAs/*.md");
    const objectBs = collectionApi.getFilteredByGlob("objectBs/*.md");
    // connect items
    objectAs.forEach(a => a.linkedB = objectBs.find(b => b.id === a.linkedBId)
    // return new collection 
    return objectAs
  });
```

Then in your template you will have to make sure you are accessing the right collection, but then you will be able to use:

```
{{ objectA.linkedB.key1 }}
```

You may need to create a new list to add to, and then return that as a new collection, so it doesn't do this in place, and edit the A collection, but do some testing and depending on how your collections are set up it might be relatively easy.